# Display list of elements in div using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be the optimum strategy to display elements in the `js` file on the following `html` page in the `div`?

**html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SO example</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="text_table"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**css file**

```
#text_table {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

**js file**

```
var testResults = [
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
];

var textTable = document.getElementById("text_table");

for (var i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
  /* leaders.innerHTML += */
};
```

Desired results is:
[image: result]

[JS fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/f4f7p6zz/5/)

Comment: Easy, but depends on how you want to render it. table, list?

Comment: @dfsq either options are OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to have a inner loop for each array inside the parent array:

```js
var testResults = [
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
];

var textTable = document.getElementById("text_table");
var nHTML = '';
for (var i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
   for(var j=0; j<testResults[i].length; j++){
      nHTML+= testResults[i][j]+ ' ';
   }
   nHTML = '<div>' + nHTML + '</div>';
}
textTable.innerHTML = nHTML;
```

```css
#text_table {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text_table"></div>
```

You can also use `.replace(/,/g, ' ')` without the inner loop like this:

```js
var testResults = [
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
  ['Nickname', 'Points', 'Time', 'Difficulty'],
];

var textTable = document.getElementById("text_table");
var nHTML = '';
for (var i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
   nHTML += '<div>' + testResults[i].toString().replace(/,/g, ' ') + '</div>';
}
textTable.innerHTML = nHTML;
```

```css
#text_table {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text_table"></div>
```